# cross product calcuation by store level in r

Tags: r

I have the following data (Which is a slight adaptation of an earlier question):

The dimensions are: `[1] 131  46`

I am trying to create a list of `chain` by `chain` product sales.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 46
  L5    ` Chain100` ` Chain103` ` Chain104` ` Chain106` ` Chain109` ` Chain15 ` ` Chain17 ` ` Chain19 ` ` Chain20 `
  <fct>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 ABBE~           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2 ANHE~           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
3 ANHE~           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
4 B E             0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
5 BACA~         124         339          16          32           0           0           0           0           0
6 BACA~           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
# ... with 36 more variables: ` Chain23 ` <dbl>, ` Chain25 ` <dbl>, ` Chain42 ` <dbl>, ` Chain43 ` <dbl>, ` Chain44
#   ` <dbl>, ` Chain47 ` <dbl>, ` Chain48 ` <dbl>, ` Chain49 ` <dbl>, ` Chain50 ` <dbl>, ` Chain52 ` <dbl>, `
#   Chain54 ` <dbl>, ` Chain57 ` <dbl>, ` Chain60 ` <dbl>, ` Chain61 ` <dbl>, ` Chain62 ` <dbl>, ` Chain65 ` <dbl>,
#   ` Chain66 ` <dbl>, ` Chain67 ` <dbl>, ` Chain68 ` <dbl>, ` Chain70 ` <dbl>, ` Chain71 ` <dbl>, ` Chain72
#   ` <dbl>, ` Chain75 ` <dbl>, ` Chain8 ` <dbl>, ` Chain80 ` <dbl>, ` Chain82 ` <dbl>, ` Chain83 ` <dbl>, ` Chain84
#   ` <dbl>, ` Chain87 ` <dbl>, ` Chain88 ` <dbl>, ` Chain89 ` <dbl>, ` Chain90 ` <dbl>, ` Chain91 ` <dbl>, `
#   Chain93 ` <dbl>, ` Chain96 ` <dbl>, ` Chain99 ` <dbl>
```

The data looks like the above. So I am interested in trying to create multiple lists for each product. That is `chain100` and `chain103` both sold `BACARDI SILVER` (along with a few other `chains`).

What I am trying to do is to make multiple lists which look like the following:

```
                       Chain1     Chain2        Chain3   Chain4

                Chain1   -                       
 BACARDI SILVER Chain2   234        -             
                Chain3   72        541          -  
                Chain4   0         231            0           -
```

So for each `row` or product there will be multiple lists (comparing the cross product purchases in each "chain").

Data:

```
structure(list(L5 = structure(1:131, .Label = c("ABBEY DE LEFFE BLONDE PALE AL", 
"ANHEUSER WORLD LAGER", "ANHEUSER WORLD SELECT", "B E", "BACARDI SILVER", 
"BACARDI SILVER LIMON", "BACARDI SILVER MOJITO", "BACARDI SILVER MOJITO PARTY P", 
"BACARDI SILVER O3", "BACARDI SILVER RAZ", "BACARDI SILVER SAMPLER", 
"BACARDI SILVER SIGNATURE", "BASS PALE ALE", "BEACH BUM BLONDE ALE", 
"BECKS", "BECKS DARK", "BECKS OKTOBERFEST", "BECKS PREMIER LIGHT", 
"BEST OF BELGIUM", "BODDINGTONS PUB CREAM ALE", "BREWMASTERS PRIVATE RESERVE", 
"BUD ICE", "BUD ICE LIGHT", "BUD LIGHT", "BUD LIGHT CHELADA", 
"BUD LIGHT GOLDEN WHEAT", "BUD LIGHT LIME", "BUD LIGHT LIME LIME A RITA", 
"BUD LIGHT PARTY PACK", "BUD LIGHT PLATINUM LAGER", "BUDWEISER", 
"BUDWEISER AMERICAN ALE", "BUDWEISER BREWMASTERS PROJECT", "BUDWEISER CHELADA", 
"BUDWEISER DRY", "BUDWEISER HAPPY HOLIDAYS", "BUDWEISER ICE DRAFT", 
"BUDWEISER MILLENNIUM", "BUDWEISER SELECT", "BUDWEISER SELECT 55", 
"BUSCH", "BUSCH ICE", "BUSCH LIGHT", "BUSCH NA", "CZECHVAR", 
"DOC OTIS HARD LEMON", "GOOSE ISLAND 312 URBAN WHEAT", "GOOSE ISLAND CHRISTMAS ALE", 
"GOOSE ISLAND HONKERS ALE", "GOOSE ISLAND IPA", "GOOSE ISLAND SEASONAL", 
"GROLSCH AMBER ALE", "GROLSCH LAGER", "GROLSCH LIGHT LAGER", 
"GROLSCH SUMMER BLONDE", "HAAKE BECK NA", "HARBIN LAGER", "HOEGAARDEN WHITE ALE", 
"HURRICANE HIGH GRAVITY", "HURRICANE HIGH GRAVITY LAGER", "HURRICANE MALT LIQUOR", 
"JACKS PUMPKIN SPICE ALE", "KILLARNEYS RED LAGER", "KING COBRA", 
"KIRIN ICHIBAN", "KIRIN ICHIBAN LAGER", "KIRIN LAGER", "KIRIN LIGHT", 
"LANDSHARK LAGER", "LOWENBRAU", "MARGARITAVILLE", "MARGARITAVILLE 5 O CLOCK", 
"MICHELOB", "MICHELOB AMBER BOCK", "MICHELOB BLACK AND TAN", 
"MICHELOB DRY", "MICHELOB DUNKEL WEISSE", "MICHELOB GOLDEN DRAFT", 
"MICHELOB GOLDEN DRAFT LIGHT", "MICHELOB HEFEWEIZEN", "MICHELOB HONEY LAGER", 
"MICHELOB IRISH RED ALE", "MICHELOB LIGHT", "MICHELOB MARZEN", 
"MICHELOB PALE ALE", "MICHELOB SEASONAL", "MICHELOB SPCLTY ALES & LGRS W", 
"MICHELOB SPECIALTY ALES & LAG", "MICHELOB ULTR POMEGRANAT RSPB", 
"MICHELOB ULTR TUSCN ORNG GRAP", "MICHELOB ULTRA", "MICHELOB ULTRA AMBER", 
"MICHELOB ULTRA DRAGON FRUIT P", "MICHELOB ULTRA FRUIT SAMPLER", 
"MICHELOB ULTRA LIGHT", "MICHELOB ULTRA LIME CACTUS", "NATTY DADDY LAGER", 
"NATURAL ICE", "NATURAL LIGHT", "ODOULS", "ODOULS AMBER", "PEELS", 
"RED WOLF", "REDBRIDGE", "ROCK GREEN LIGHT", "ROCK LIGHT", "ROLLING ROCK EXTRA PALE", 
"ROLLING ROCK LIGHT", "SAINT PAULI GIRL", "SAINT PAULI GIRL DARK", 
"SAINT PAULI N A", "SHADOWS WILD BLACK LAGER", "SHOCK TOP BELGIAN WHITE ALE", 
"SHOCK TOP PUMPKIN WHEAT", "SHOCK TOP RASPBERRY WHEAT ALE", "SHOCK TOP SEASONAL", 
"SHOCK TOP VARIETY PACK", "SHOCK TOP WHEAT IPA", "SPRING HEAT SPICED WHEAT", 
"STELLA ARTOIS LAGER", "STONE MILL", "TAKE 6 HOME", "TEQUIZA", 
"TIGER LAGER", "TILT", "TILT 8 PERCENT", "ULTRA 19TH HOLE", "WHITBREAD TRADITIONAL PALE AL", 
"WILD BLUE", "WILD HOP", "WILD HOP ORGANIC LAGER"), class = "factor"), 
    ` Chain100` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 124, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 154, 1053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1046, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 661, 1, 585, 64, 0, 41, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 127, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 63, 0, 
    361, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 241, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 233, 508, 
    146, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 256, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain103` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 339, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 530, 284, 2309, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2252, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1464, 3, 1391, 171, 0, 157, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
    47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 422, 249, 91, 0, 0, 1, 6, 43, 131, 0, 853, 0, 0, 0, 
    18, 0, 0, 0, 138, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 401, 1188, 375, 113, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 587, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain104` = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 33, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 91, 17, 336, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 312, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 238, 5, 295, 38, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 53, 25, 
    14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 104, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 154, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), ` Chain106` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 633, 266, 2230, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 2115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1540, 103, 1561, 190, 
    0, 194, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    77, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 528, 225, 112, 0, 0, 74, 
    168, 43, 113, 0, 865, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 299, 1236, 373, 116, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 501, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), ` Chain109` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 104, 36, 346, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 297, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 237, 8, 303, 31, 0, 35, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55, 20, 17, 0, 0, 12, 17, 0, 4, 0, 109, 0, 
    0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 179, 32, 6, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain15 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 
    0, 663, 0, 1, 17, 0, 0, 14, 466, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    30, 263, 0, 336, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 55, 129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain17 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 149, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 92, 0, 106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 38, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain19 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 124, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    3, 0, 62, 0, 74, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain20 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    16, 0, 54, 0, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 6, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain23 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain25 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 3, 0, 86, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 37, 0, 14, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain42 ` = c(63, 
    0, 0, 0, 173, 0, 376, 0, 7, 265, 0, 0, 346, 0, 518, 326, 
    25, 160, 6, 169, 0, 663, 249, 3570, 243, 0, 521, 0, 0, 0, 
    3382, 87, 0, 147, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1620, 0, 1513, 98, 1655, 319, 
    12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 48, 5, 157, 0, 37, 0, 6, 
    0, 52, 65, 0, 0, 12, 489, 66, 0, 0, 393, 650, 0, 0, 19, 0, 
    0, 0, 52, 0, 990, 96, 23, 150, 51, 20, 286, 105, 1430, 537, 
    0, 25, 0, 326, 0, 821, 1697, 471, 181, 0, 0, 77, 322, 70, 
    744, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 156, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 482, 2, 0, 68, 
    0, 32, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5), ` Chain43 ` = c(37, 0, 0, 0, 4, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 101, 252, 0, 602, 225, 35, 107, 0, 210, 
    0, 1343, 0, 6191, 279, 244, 2003, 242, 0, 642, 5266, 64, 
    16, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2755, 2284, 2598, 59, 2992, 566, 30, 
    0, 205, 6, 36, 96, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0, 327, 18, 43, 0, 
    0, 0, 188, 15, 6, 0, 14, 1061, 0, 30, 0, 121, 1175, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 1069, 3, 0, 54, 21, 0, 424, 0, 2972, 535, 
    144, 9, 78, 457, 0, 2064, 3224, 845, 431, 0, 0, 455, 0, 29, 
    1180, 0, 261, 111, 36, 0, 539, 37, 390, 193, 15, 34, 0, 1400, 
    0, 103, 0, 0, 327, 14, 6, 0, 219, 0, 0), ` Chain44 ` = c(45, 
    0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 62, 6, 0, 104, 0, 113, 167, 0, 359, 209, 
    15, 62, 0, 139, 0, 694, 59, 3604, 207, 495, 1092, 0, 24, 
    0, 3085, 273, 0, 46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1609, 969, 1377, 81, 1580, 
    337, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42, 0, 166, 0, 52, 
    0, 0, 0, 98, 35, 0, 0, 11, 618, 1, 0, 0, 174, 566, 0, 0, 
    29, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 820, 29, 3, 120, 55, 0, 285, 65, 1430, 
    371, 138, 0, 0, 284, 0, 909, 1683, 455, 177, 0, 0, 177, 2, 
    120, 722, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 209, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 503, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 9, 62, 0, 0, 89, 0, 0), ` Chain47 ` = c(48, 0, 0, 0, 
    117, 0, 314, 20, 0, 247, 0, 29, 261, 0, 477, 276, 8, 108, 
    0, 145, 0, 698, 219, 3641, 231, 167, 1108, 0, 0, 0, 3272, 
    368, 0, 89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1647, 163, 1453, 79, 1662, 343, 23, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42, 1, 154, 0, 51, 0, 0, 0, 
    62, 36, 0, 0, 4, 613, 33, 0, 0, 239, 632, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 
    0, 126, 32, 921, 87, 69, 135, 185, 0, 298, 173, 1440, 496, 
    0, 65, 0, 320, 0, 843, 1715, 457, 185, 0, 0, 73, 2, 271, 
    737, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 455, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 24, 77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain48 ` = c(46, 38, 0, 71, 
    631, 0, 137, 0, 287, 476, 0, 0, 315, 44, 473, 280, 29, 180, 
    12, 137, 0, 1241, 838, 5938, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5550, 0, 0, 
    0, 47, 28, 0, 0, 3154, 0, 2664, 69, 2973, 602, 8, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 484, 15, 38, 45, 27, 133, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 105, 
    70, 0, 0, 19, 0, 141, 0, 0, 917, 1129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    102, 0, 1883, 22, 0, 0, 0, 63, 33, 25, 2355, 958, 0, 0, 0, 
    58, 0, 1243, 2922, 877, 349, 374, 0, 61, 401, 0, 1251, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 333, 102, 0, 163, 39, 158, 
    11, 0, 0, 0, 96, 0), ` Chain49 ` = c(4, 30, 37, 67, 721, 
    0, 29, 0, 376, 452, 2, 0, 44, 8, 25, 39, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 
    853, 490, 3820, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3716, 0, 0, 0, 67, 11, 
    0, 0, 1632, 0, 1974, 0, 2066, 390, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    252, 0, 8, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 52, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 710, 792, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 95, 0, 1363, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    22, 0, 0, 1717, 95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 874, 1979, 606, 180, 143, 
    0, 6, 41, 0, 833, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 46, 
    13, 0, 90, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0), ` Chain50 ` = c(0, 
    0, 126, 0, 357, 133, 0, 0, 453, 415, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 732, 523, 2985, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2927, 0, 0, 
    0, 83, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1722, 0, 1767, 413, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 188, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 28, 0, 3, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 687, 629, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 139, 0, 1106, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 1387, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 706, 1660, 
    475, 221, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 182, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain52 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 450, 0, 0, 0, 440, 122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 699, 518, 2710, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2670, 0, 0, 0, 
    67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1650, 8, 1686, 417, 0, 186, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 155, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 14, 0, 21, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 726, 572, 194, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99, 199, 0, 1032, 
    0, 0, 0, 17, 24, 0, 0, 932, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 729, 1550, 
    459, 215, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 685, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 244, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain54 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 418, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 672, 484, 2349, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2232, 0, 0, 0, 72, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1411, 38, 1381, 399, 0, 241, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 
    151, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 52, 3, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 648, 405, 172, 1, 0, 7, 27, 139, 194, 0, 966, 0, 0, 
    0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 177, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 639, 1293, 432, 264, 
    0, 52, 0, 0, 0, 633, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 307, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain57 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 552, 346, 1586, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1627, 0, 0, 0, 74, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1037, 37, 1060, 311, 0, 191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 
    168, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 116, 49, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 482, 310, 111, 0, 0, 75, 304, 96, 151, 0, 685, 0, 
    0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 424, 899, 296, 199, 
    0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 457, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 258, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain60 ` = c(21, 
    0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 359, 7, 0, 169, 13, 0, 236, 0, 327, 205, 8, 
    75, 0, 86, 0, 296, 70, 1707, 71, 0, 333, 0, 0, 0, 1649, 61, 
    0, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 954, 0, 700, 0, 873, 239, 12, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 389, 0, 0, 0, 184, 468, 0, 0, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 549, 
    26, 14, 64, 28, 1, 120, 0, 1066, 420, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 319, 
    662, 419, 41, 1, 0, 41, 147, 51, 483, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 94, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 247, 42, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0, 116, 0, 
    11), ` Chain61 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 
    135, 0, 262, 98, 0, 58, 0, 113, 0, 426, 3, 1695, 0, 79, 641, 
    50, 0, 152, 1564, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 858, 794, 796, 0, 
    911, 203, 0, 0, 66, 0, 31, 48, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 106, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 354, 0, 49, 11, 125, 347, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 456, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 192, 0, 909, 286, 
    0, 0, 51, 185, 0, 460, 672, 378, 178, 0, 0, 139, 0, 23, 264, 
    7, 92, 31, 0, 23, 198, 0, 138, 48, 13, 0, 0, 395, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 89, 0, 0), ` Chain62 ` = c(41, 0, 0, 0, 35, 
    0, 176, 7, 0, 23, 0, 35, 167, 0, 232, 143, 0, 92, 0, 85, 
    0, 254, 21, 1464, 25, 245, 596, 0, 25, 0, 1348, 196, 0, 23, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 788, 537, 608, 0, 703, 212, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 358, 
    0, 0, 0, 141, 362, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 392, 23, 6, 45, 
    40, 0, 183, 0, 822, 279, 0, 0, 0, 179, 0, 282, 562, 353, 
    101, 0, 0, 46, 0, 72, 367, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 181, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 264, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 170, 0, 0), ` Chain65 ` = c(58, 
    0, 0, 3, 7, 0, 382, 20, 18, 258, 0, 0, 530, 0, 691, 473, 
    0, 138, 0, 184, 0, 984, 280, 5247, 60, 58, 682, 0, 0, 0, 
    5073, 307, 0, 63, 0, 6, 0, 0, 2635, 95, 2176, 1, 2711, 734, 
    23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 381, 0, 0, 0, 0, 164, 0, 0, 0, 5, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 453, 0, 0, 0, 588, 1419, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 
    0, 27, 0, 1623, 70, 35, 75, 109, 58, 230, 0, 2989, 1200, 
    0, 0, 0, 229, 0, 1028, 2053, 1278, 130, 546, 0, 96, 180, 
    124, 1404, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 207, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 520, 64, 
    0, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 213, 28, 0), ` Chain66 ` = c(0, 0, 
    0, 48, 193, 0, 43, 1, 121, 290, 9, 13, 5, 0, 4, 9, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 5, 647, 258, 2806, 54, 8, 188, 0, 0, 0, 2638, 20, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 691, 61, 1478, 42, 1653, 322, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 242, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 83, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 
    0, 2, 113, 0, 26, 0, 427, 573, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 87, 0, 767, 
    0, 0, 4, 0, 27, 49, 0, 1236, 31, 18, 4, 0, 63, 0, 560, 1041, 
    470, 48, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 564, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 14, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 45, 0, 13, 13, 0, 0), ` Chain67 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 0, 0, 336, 224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 617, 308, 2310, 0, 0, 100, 44, 0, 80, 2135, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 64, 48, 1227, 23, 1354, 261, 0, 8, 2, 3, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 221, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 33, 0, 8, 0, 514, 512, 6, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 62, 0, 753, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 4, 21, 0, 1091, 0, 4, 0, 14, 25, 0, 433, 921, 458, 
    46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 509, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 31, 7, 0, 
    0, 18, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain68 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 18, 7, 3, 27, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 68, 10, 470, 33, 23, 132, 0, 2, 0, 387, 19, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 65, 64, 282, 18, 298, 75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 5, 0, 18, 0, 0, 21, 
    1, 173, 0, 16, 0, 0, 35, 0, 58, 126, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
    52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
    34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain70 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 356, 0, 0, 
    0, 303, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 422, 319, 1508, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1429, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 884, 0, 
    943, 192, 0, 123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 126, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 548, 387, 122, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 103, 0, 673, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 551, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 251, 716, 393, 123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 390, 35, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), ` Chain71 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 20, 2, 14, 26, 
    0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 80, 26, 474, 30, 9, 111, 
    0, 0, 0, 377, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 10, 277, 27, 285, 
    56, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 41, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 57, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    11, 54, 13, 3, 20, 0, 4, 17, 9, 155, 2, 0, 10, 0, 32, 0, 
    80, 127, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 35, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), ` Chain72 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 244, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 315, 243, 1039, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1020, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 688, 0, 781, 155, 0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 81, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    429, 257, 93, 0, 0, 14, 13, 0, 84, 0, 491, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 
    0, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 169, 659, 297, 136, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 247, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 196, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain75 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 332, 230, 818, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 805, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 731, 0, 
    708, 152, 0, 173, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 71, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 423, 241, 123, 0, 
    0, 92, 139, 0, 121, 0, 467, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 643, 262, 127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 264, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 220, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), ` Chain8  ` = c(0, 0, 0, 11, 72, 15, 0, 0, 97, 
    43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 202, 131, 959, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 919, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 519, 0, 495, 
    78, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 219, 124, 41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 46, 0, 414, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 428, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    247, 482, 167, 75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 243, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain80 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 53, 0, 573, 0, 2, 58, 0, 0, 0, 312, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 3, 1, 201, 0, 247, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), ` Chain82 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 41, 11, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 42, 218, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    207, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 108, 0, 208, 0, 0, 34, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 59, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 105, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 104, 65, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain83 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 
    0, 1151, 4, 0, 92, 0, 0, 43, 696, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 101, 
    0, 450, 0, 442, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 181, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 89, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 72, 70, 232, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    ` Chain84 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 104, 45, 744, 1, 9, 61, 0, 0, 0, 557, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 3, 372, 0, 479, 0, 0, 34, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 97, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 76, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 114, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 221, 71, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain87 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 
    8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 
    8, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 
    3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain88 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 57, 0, 558, 1, 7, 41, 0, 0, 0, 395, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 45, 0, 219, 0, 241, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 47, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), ` Chain89 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 5, 
    0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 147, 0, 843, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 717, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 0, 450, 0, 317, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 165, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 102, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 48, 199, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain90 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 0, 332, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 292, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 0, 149, 0, 
    64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 
    51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain91 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 44, 0, 359, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 372, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 149, 0, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 87, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    ` Chain93 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 354, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 411, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 202, 0, 60, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain96 ` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 294, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 347, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 185, 0, 42, 
    7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 
    0, 112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 43, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 
    55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ` Chain99 ` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 4, 73, 0, 25, 0, 20, 42, 17, 0, 3, 0, 7, 15, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 3, 118, 27, 695, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 732, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    4, 0, 0, 85, 0, 385, 28, 333, 43, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 41, 5, 0, 3, 84, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 68, 59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 171, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
    0, 13, 132, 40, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 108, 214, 17, 0, 1, 0, 3, 
    29, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 34, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -131L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```